# How to create list of checkboxes with scroll?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, checkbox, scrollbar

I'm trying this code:

```
arrList = new List<CheckBox>();
for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
{
    CheckBox check = new CheckBox();
    arrList.Add(check);
}
CheckBox[] cb = arrList.ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    cb[i].Text = "sometext";
    cb[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 15 + i * 20);
    cb[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;
    cb[i].Name = "somename";
    cb[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(59, 17);
    cb[i].Checked = true;
    groupBox1.Controls.Add(cb[i]);
}
```

How can I add a vertical scroll bar there? (maybe I should use something instead of groupbox?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `Panel` control and set it's `AutoScroll` property to True